# Place Image On White Background Using Imagick

Tags: php, gd, imagick

Here is a GD version of what I intend to do. It places an image at the centre of a white background.

```
$background = imagecreatetruecolor(709,709);
$whiteBackground = imagecolorallocate($background, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($background,0,0,$whiteBackground);
imagecopyresampled(
    $background, $new_img,(709-$imageWidth)/2,(709-$imageHeight)/2,
    0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $width, $height
);
ImageJpeg ($background,"$path/$newName.$file_ext", 85);`
```

But I want it carried out using Imagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO,

What you are looking for is flatten;

```
$im = new Imagick($old_img);
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(11);
$im->mergeImageLayers(imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
$im->setFormat("png");

$new = fopen($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $newName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_ext, "w");
$im->writeImageFile($new);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Not saying this is exactly what you are looking for, but it should help you well on your way.
the `$im->setImageAlphaChannel(11);` 
can be replaced by `$im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);` if your Imagic version is
3.2.0b2 or higher

Comment: @user5156411 please acceot the answer if it works for you or at least upvote if it helped you. Help the comunity find better questions/answeres

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted the answer and I thought it would tick it. I never knew you had to click on the tick icon itself to mark it as the accepted answer. I am a newbie here and I was told my upvotes will not indicate yet.